# How to add Label at customized position in XY chart in chartdirector in C++?

Tags: c++, mfc, chart-director

I want to add a customized Label at customized position in XY chart in chartdirector in C++.
For example, add a number label at (20, 40) on the plotarea.

```
// Create a XYChart object of size 740 x 760 pixels
XYChart* c = new XYChart(740, 760);

// Set the plotarea at (45, 25) and of size 680 x 680 pixels, with a light grey border
// (0xc0c0c0). Turn on both horizontal and vertical grid lines with light grey color (0xc0c0c0)
c->setPlotArea(45, 25, 680, 680, -1, -1, 0xc0c0c0, 0xc0c0c0, -1);

// Add a title to the chart using 18pt Times Bold Itatic font.
c->addTitle("X-Y Scatter Plot", "timesbi.ttf", 10);

// Add a title to the y axis using 12pt Arial Bold Italic font
c->yAxis()->setTitle("Y Distance (m)", "arialbi.ttf", 8);

// Add a title to the y axis using 12pt Arial Bold Italic font
c->xAxis()->setTitle("X Distance (m)", "arialbi.ttf", 8);

// Set the axes line width to 3 pixels
c->xAxis()->setWidth(2);
c->yAxis()->setWidth(2);

// Set the x and y axis to scale 
c->xAxis()->setLinearScale((set_xy_range + margin_distance) * (-1), set_xy_range + margin_distance, set_xy_range_r);
c->yAxis()->setLinearScale((set_xy_range + margin_distance) * (-1), set_xy_range + margin_distance, set_xy_range_r);

XYChartView.setChart(c);
```

Can you please advice?

Comment: you can use addText method of the XYChart object

Comment: Thanks you. Can you give an example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cpp
// Add a customized label at position (20, 40)
TextBox* label = c->addText(20, 40, "Your Label", "arial.ttf", 10);
label->setAlignment(Chart::TopLeft);
label->setBackground(0xFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFF, 1);
```

Added optional `setAlignment`.